# Modifying an isometry in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $f(x,y) = (y,x)$, we know that $f$ is an Isometry in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ with usual metrics. Now, find a norm for $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ such that $f$ is not an isometry.

Hint: Think about two distinct metrics $d_{1}$ and $d_{2}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\mathbb{R},d_{1}) \times (\mathbb{R},d_{2}) = \mathbb{R^{2}}.$

My problem is how can I combine two metrics into one in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$? I think that I need to rotate $f$ somehow but I'm really lost.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Define a new metric by d((x,y),(p,q))=d_1(x,p)+d_2(y,q).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of inducing a metric on the product $X \times Y$ of two metric spaces from metrics $d_X$ on $X$ and $d_Y$ on $Y$: if $d$ is any metric on $\Bbb{R}^2$, then if you put $\rho((x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2)) = d(d_X(x_1, x_2), d_Y(y_1, y_2))$, then $\rho$ will be a metric on $X \times Y$. In this case, you have $X = Y = \Bbb{R}$ and if you take $d$ to be the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}^2$, and choose metrics on $X$ and $Y$ which assign different lengths to the interval $[-1, 1]$ you will get a metric $\rho$ for which your $f$ is not an isometry. E.g., take $d_X(x, y) = |x-y|/2$ and $d_Y(x, y) = 2|x-y|$.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't change $f$.

Can you show that
$$
d:\mathbb{R}^2\times\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R},~\big((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\big)\mapsto d_1(x_1,y_1) + d_2(x_2,y_2)
$$
is a metric if $d_1$ and $d_2$ are?